# How can I run a terminal command in my swift menu bar app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, terminal

I have made a menu bar app and I want this command to be run on press

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

The code I currently have is this:

```
@IBAction func toggleClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {

    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["rm", "-rf", "~/.Trash/*"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()

}
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
/bin/rm: /bin/rm: cannot execute binary file
```

I dont really understand why I'm getting this error since I can open terminal and run /bin/sh, then enter in rm -rf ~/.Trash/* and it works as expected.

**EDIT**

I have tried to change the commands to this but nothing happens:

```
    task.launchPath = "/bin/rm"
    task.arguments = ["-rf", "~/.Trash/*"]
```

Comment: try `("~/.Trash/*" as NSString).stringByStandardizingPath`

Comment: Where would I put that in?

Comment: task.arguments = ["-rf", ("~/.Trash/*" as NSString).stringByStandardizingPath] doesn't work

Comment: is the app sandboxed? If yes, you might add appropriate entitlements

Comment: How can I make this command sudo?

Comment: You can't easily. For sudo you need a helper process with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make [/bin/sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) read from the command line string you need to pass the -c argument.

Your code needs to be changed as follows:

```
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", "rm -rf ~/.Trash/*"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks :) Is there an easy way to run this as sudo if needed?

Comment: Looks like I don't need it with this command even if  the file is in use which is great!